# jQuery to click select button on a gridview row

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, button, gridview

I have a simple gridview with autogenerated select buttons:

```
<asp:Gridview runat="server" id="gvChemDates" CssClass="c_gvv" 
    onselectedindexchanged="getValues" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" />
```

I want to hide the select column and allow my user to select it by clicking anywhere on the row. Using jQuery, I tried several variations of this:

```
$('#gvChemDates tr').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('input[type=submit]').trigger('click');
})
```

But nothing I do seems to click that autogenerated select button. Can someone tell me the correct syntax to do this? Thanks.

Comment: .closest() searches the current node level and traverses upwards, (https://api.jquery.com/closest/), I think you are wanting to use .find() instead of .closest()

Comment: I assume that "auto generated" is dynamic? Try something like  `$('#gvChemDates').on('click', ' tr', function () {...});`

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Selecting-GridView-Row-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-Row.aspx

Comment: if you want to do this more simple check my Answer

Answer (score 0):

`$('#gvChemDates tr')` will not work (`#gvChemDates` not exist) because ASP.NET generate random id when using `runat="server"`

Use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to ensure client id matches server id:

```
<asp:Gridview runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" id="gvChemDates" CssClass="c_gvv" 
    onselectedindexchanged="getValues" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" />
```

**Note**: when you use `runat="server"` ASP.NET generate random id for client id. So we use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to make client id matches server id.

Answer (score -1):

**Jquery function with GridView select button**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="moreDetail" runat="server" CommandName="select" Text="More Detail" onclientclick="pageLoad()" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**JQuery function**

```
function pageLoad() {
    var gvid = '<%=GridDetail.ClientID %>';
    $('#' + gvid + ' input[type=button]').removeAttr('onclick');
    $('#' + gvid + ' input[type=button]').click(function () {

        //$('#' + gvid + ' tr').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        //row.css('background-color', '#669999');
        var cells = row.find('td'); // busca el valor de cada columna en el record releccionado.

        var premAmount = row.find('td').eq(7).html();
        var commAmount = row.find('td').eq(8).html();
        var account = row.find('td').eq(9).find(':input').val();
        var loan = row.find('td').eq(10).find(':input').val();
        var tranType = row.find('td').eq(11).find(':input').val();
        var semsys = row.find('td').eq(12).find(':input').val();
        var prodName = row.find('td').eq(13).find(':input').val();
        var contact = row.find('td').eq(15).find(':input').val();

        var commPercent = (parseFloat(commAmount.replace(/[$,]+/g, "")) / parseFloat(premAmount.replace(/[$,]+/g, ""))) * 100;

        $('#Span1').html(cells[0].innerHTML); // 1 
        $('#Span2').html(cells[1].innerHTML); // 2 certificate
        $('#Span3').html(tranType);
        $('#Span4').html(cells[2].innerHTML); // 4 insured
        $('#Span5').html(cells[4].innerHTML); // 5 eff date
        $('#Span6').html(cells[5].innerHTML); // 6 exp date
        $('#Span7').html(cells[6].innerHTML); // 7 cancel date
        $('#Span8').html(cells[3].innerHTML); // 8  type
        $('#Span9').html(loan);
        $('#Span10').html(account); // ******
        $('#Span11').html(premAmount);
        $('#Span12').html(commAmount);
        $('#Span13').html(prodName); // *****
        $('#Span14').html(semsys); // *******
        $('#Span15').html(commPercent); //****
        $('#Span16').html(contact); // ******

        $('div#Div_Details').slideToggle("slow"); //animation
        $('div#Div_Details').slideDown("slow");


    });   
};
```